# Magento 2.0 Custom system.xml, How to include external JS

Tags: magento2

I need the google maps library in my s`ystem.xml`.  where should i put the inlcude files? I already created the `view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` file but I am not sure how to use it to render the included JS in the header.

This is how the `requirejs-config.js` looks like:

```
    var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            gmap:             'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.18&libraries=geometry,places',
            gmaps:            'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gmaps.js/0.4.22/gmaps.min.js',
            jqueryGeolocation:'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Geolocation/1.0.50/jquery.geolocation.min.js'
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep below code inside your requirejs-config.js file,

```
var config = {
    paths: {
            gmap:             'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.18&libraries=geometry,places',
            gmaps:            'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gmaps.js/0.4.22/gmaps.min',
            jqueryGeolocation:'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Geolocation/1.0.50/jquery.geolocation.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'gmap': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'gmaps': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'jqueryGeolocation': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
    }
};
```

Run deploy command, `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
Plz check using this.